# How to add Wordpress featured image via SQL

Tags: wp-query, images

I have thousands of custom post types called "listings" without images.
Now I want to add an image to each of these listings as a placeholder image and these images should be also set as featured images. The image to each listing should be the same e.g. default.jpg.

Can anyone help me writing a SQL query doing this?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

I can tell how to do it with WordPress functions, which is quite easy and you won't lose any important stuff:

1. Upload the default.jpg image using WordPress media manager. Note the ID of the image.
2. Get all posts from your custom post type and run `set_post_thumbnail()` for each one.

Example: add this code to functions.php of your theme or in a plugin. Visit the admin side of you site to make it run. Delete it after the job has been done (otherwise it will be executed every time the admin area is visited).

```
add_action('admin_init', function () {
    //Replace with the correct image ID
    $image_id = 45;
    $args = array(
        'nopaging'   => true,
        'post_type'  => 'listings'
    );
    $listings = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $listings as $listing) {
        //if has not featured image assigned, set default
        if( ! has_post_thumbnail($listing->ID) ) {
            set_post_thumbnail( $listing->ID, $image_id );
        }
    }
} );
```

Alternative: don't set default image for every post. Instead check if post has thumbnail (featured image), if not display default.jpg:

```
//Assuming we are inside the loop
if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} else {
    echo '<img src="http://url.com/to/default.jpg">';
}
```